# How to customize keyboard in ios in order to use other language

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I want to make khmer keyboard for ios. How to make this keyboard in objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should create a view with buttons for the respective language alphabets, which looks like iPhone keyboard and set this view as inputview for textfield as

textField.inputView = yourkeyboarview;

Comment: https://github.com/caydenliew/CLKeypad check this, you can use this as reference, (uncomment the code in -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField method in viewController.m )